# Perturbed real roots of an exponential-polynomial equation

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

**Question:** Develop three terms of the perturbation solutions to the real roots of
$$(x^3 + 2x^2 + x)e^{-x} = \epsilon,$$
identifying the scalings in the expansion sequence $\delta_0(\epsilon)x_0 + \delta_1(\epsilon)x_1 + \delta_2(\epsilon)x_2 + \cdots$.

**My approach:** The equation can be rewritten as follows:
$$x(x+1)^2e^{-x} = \epsilon.$$
Taking the natural log of both sides of the equation, we arrive at the following equation:
$$\ln(x) + 2\ln(x+1) -x = \ln(\epsilon),$$
which implies that
$$x = \ln(x) + 2\ln(x+1) - \ln(\epsilon).$$

This leads us to the following iteration scheme to find out the two real perturbed roots:
$$x_{n+1} = \ln(x_n) + 2\ln(x_n+1) - \ln(\epsilon),$$
for all $n\ge\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$.

To find the smaller root, we can choose the starting point $x_0 = \epsilon$, and for the larger root, a good starting point can be $x_0 = -3\ln(\epsilon)$ or $x_0 = -4\ln(\epsilon)$.

However, I am not being able to find a stable expansion sequence for both roots. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Are you assuming $\epsilon>0$ ? If $\epsilon$ is small and negative you can have three solutions.

Comment: I added a nice formula which is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the small root, why not to use Taylor expansion followed by power series reversion to get
$$x=\epsilon -\epsilon ^2+\frac{5 }{2}\epsilon ^3-\frac{22}{3}\epsilon ^4+O\left(\epsilon ^5\right)$$ which also gives some bounds.

For the large root, start Newton method with $x_0=-k\log(\epsilon)$ such that
$$f(x_0) \times f''(x_0) >0$$ with
$$f(x)=-x+\log(x) + 2\log(x+1) - \log(\epsilon)$$ This ensures, by Darboux theorem, that the solution will be reached without any overshoot..

Since $$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{(x+1)^2} ~<~0 \quad \forall x>0$$ it suffices the select $k$ such that $f(x_0)<0$

If $\epsilon=e^{-n}$, at least for $1\leq n \leq 10$
$$k = \left\lceil \frac{6}{n}+\frac{3}{2}\right\rceil$$ seems to be a good choice.

Trying for $n=18$, $k=2$; Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & x_p \\
 0 & 36.000000 \\
 1 & 28.164131 \\
 2 & 28.074611 \\
 3 & 28.074595 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If the equation had been
$$f(x)=-x+\log(x) + 2\log(x+\color{red}{0}) - \log(\epsilon)$$ with $\epsilon=e^{n}$ and $x=-k\log(\epsilon)$, we should have
$$k=-\frac 3 n \,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3} e^{-n/3}\right)$$ but, for this value $f(x_0)>0$.

But
$$\color{blue}{k=\frac 12-\frac 3 n \,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3} e^{-n/3}\right)}$$ is fine $\forall n \geq 1$.